# Regular Expression, how to get a contents texts into array?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match-all

```
[code]
 [1] text 1
 [2] text 2
 [3] text 3
[/code]
```

so I need that the values `text 1, text 2, text 3` was as array.

My troubles in this:

```
$matches = preg_match_all( "/^\[\d{1,3}\](.*)/", $content, $tags );
```

It's returns me an array with empty values:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

)
1
```

How to fix it or make it good?

```
[code]
 [1] text 1
 Different content here
 [2] text 2 Another dif..
 [3] Also something either
  to be continues!
[/code]
```

With multiline it will return only a `text 1` instead of all code in array's first element

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [1] text 1


            [1] => [2] text 2 Another dif..

            [2] => [3] Also something either

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  text 1


            [1] =>  text 2 Another dif..

            [2] =>  Also something either

        )

)
1
```

And other elements too will be only by a first string result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should drop the anchor `^` and change `(.*)` to a look-ahead set `([^[]*)` instead.

```
$s =<<<EOM
[code]
 [1] text 1
 Another line
 [2] text 2
 And another line too
 [3] text 3
[/code]
EOM;

preg_match_all("/\[\d{1,3}\]([^[]*)/", $s, $tags);

print_r($tags);
```

Comment: actually, there is can be a lot of spaces everywhere, but the structure is the same as I wrote.

Comment: @VictorCzechov that's fine, but between the start of the line until the first square bracket is where you want to have the `\s*`, like in my answer. Try and let me know.

Comment: I did whole inline `[code] [1] text 1 [2] text 2 [3] text 3 [/code]` and it's gave me the array, Array [pre]
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  [1] text 1 [2] text 2 [3] text 3 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  text 1 [2] text 2 [3] text 3 
        )

)
1[/pre]

Comment: sorry, still have troubles with comments edition, but watch in the top of question soon.

Comment: @VictorCzechov no problem, I've edited your question to remove the stuff that can be found from looking at the answers :)

Comment: I was too fast seems, have a question still.